# Array type being picked up as array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, tridion, tridion-2011

I have some simple Javascript looping through an array of items (Tridion User Groups) to check if the user is a member of a specific group.

I can easily code around the issue shown below ( see `&& extensionGroup !== 'true'`) but I want to understand why the `isArray` = `true` is counted as a *value* in the array - any ideas?

The screenshot below demonstrates that the value `extensionGroups` has been set thus

```
var extensionGroups = ["NotEvenARealGroup", "Author", "ExampleGroupAfterOneUserIsActuallyIn"];
```

but returns the `isArray` value as a 4th value?

*updated to show images a little clearer*

[image: Firebug - objects]

[image: Firebug - code]

Comment: It's not. It's a property in the object.

Comment: The better question is why did someone add `isArray` to the Array prototype... wouldn't it always be true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `for in` to iterate an array; don't do that. Use `for` (or `forEach`):

```
for(var i = 0; i < extensionGroups.length; i++) {
    var extensionGroup = extensionGroups[i];
    // ...
}
```

The reason this fails is because `for in` is used to iterate over an object's properties in JavaScript. Iterating over an array in this way means you get anything else assigned to it, such as this property or `length`.

And if you're able to use `Array#forEach`, it's probably most appropriate here:

```
extensionGroups.forEach(function(extensionGroup) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That's great thank Minitech - I've just scribbled the code in and then missed the glaringly obvious when debugging!!! Cheers for the prompt responsive.

Answer (score 1):

`For..in`, technically speaking, doesn't iterate through values. It iterates through property names. In an array, the values ARE properties, under the hood. So when you iterate over them with `for..in` you get funky stuff like that happening.

Which highlights my next point: **don't use `for..in`**. Don't use it for arrays -- don't use it for anything, really. Ok -- maybe that's going a bit too far. How about this: if you feel the need to use `for..in`, think hard to see if it's justifiable before you do it.

Comment: Don't use it for *anything*? I think that needs a little basis in fact... `for in` is excellent when used for what it's intended to do, and that is iterate an object's properties.

Comment: Consider myself slapped - thanks for the heads-up. I've always used the method minitech mentions above but for some reason hadn't here and couldn't see the wood for the trees! resolved now so thanks :)

Comment: @minitech I mean.. I guess. But how often do you really need to iterate through all of an objects properties in javascript? I dunno -- maybe its just my programming style, but in several years of js programming I don't know if I've used it once

Comment: I do it about once per project, but no `for in` means no jQuery :)

Comment: @minitech in terms of jQuery's source, you mean?